# Redirect input and output of subshell to anonymous fd

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In bash I know that `cmd1 <(cmd2)` redirects the stdout of `cmd2` to an anonymous file descriptor. `cmd1` receives an argument like `/dev/fd/12` from which it can read. I would like something like `cmd1 <>(cmd2)`, so that `cmd1` is able to read and write on the file descriptor.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs

Comment: @Mat How would that work for multiple subshells?

Comment: Not differently from how it works with different processes